# Transform RDD into RowMatrix for PCA

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The original data I have looks like this:

RDD data:

> key -> index
>
> 1     ->   2
>
> 1     ->   3
>
> 1     ->  5
>
> 2 ->       1
>
> 2  ->      3
>
> 2   ->     4

How can I convert the RDD to the following format?

> key -> index1, index2, index3, index4, index5
>
> 1 -> 0,1,1,0,1
>
> 2 -> 1,0,1,1,0

My current method is:

```
    val vectors = filtered_data_by_key.map( x => {
    var temp = Array[AnyVal]()
    x._2.copyToArray(temp)
    (x._1, Vectors.sparse(filtered_key_size, temp.map(_.asInstanceOf[Int]), Array.fill(filtered_key_size)(1) ))
})
```

I got some strange error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 54.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 54.0 (TID 75, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed

When I try to debug this program using the following code:

```
val vectors = filtered_data_by_key.map( x => {
    val temp = Array[AnyVal]()
    val t = x._2.copyToArray(temp)
    (x._1, temp)
})
```

I found temp is empty, so the problem is in `copyToArray()`.

I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: the copyToArray method requires temp to be type AnyVal, after I convert temp to AnyVal and call copyToarray, the result is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question completely. Why are your keys important? And what is the maximum index value? In your code you arre using distinct number of keys as the maximum value of index but I believe that is a mistake.

But I will assume the maximum index value is 5. In that case, I believe this would be what you're looking for:

```
val vectors = data_by_key.map({case(k,it)=>Vectors.sparse(5,it.map(x=>x-1).toArray,
        Array.fill(it.size)(1))})

val rm = new RowMatrix(vectors)
```

I decreased index number by one because they should start with 0.

The error 'requirement failed' is due to your index and values vectors not having the same size.

Comment: how can I convert from (key, iterator) to RowMatrix?